# Errors: "sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table positions has no column named Kategorie"

Tags: android, database, eclipse, sdk

I want to create a database, after running LogCat i get following Errors:

1. sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table positions has no column named Kategorie"
2. Bad request for field slot 0,4. numRows = 52, numColumns = 4"

My code is as follows:

**Databasehandler.java**

```
package com.androidhive.androidsqlite;
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
// Database Version

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PositionManager";

// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_POSITIONS = "positions";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";

private static final String KEY_NAME = "Name";

private static final String KEY_KATEGORIE = "kategorie";

private static final String KEY_LAENGE = "Laenge";

private static final String KEY_BREITE = "Breite";  

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {

    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

// Creating Tables

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_POSITIONS + "("+ KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_KATEGORIE + " TEXT," + KEY_LAENGE + " TEXT,"+ KEY_BREITE + " TEXT" + ")";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
}

// Upgrading database

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Drop older table if existed
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_POSITIONS);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);
}

/**

 * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations

 */

// Adding new contact

void addPosition(Position position) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_NAME, position.getName()); //  Name

    values.put(KEY_KATEGORIE, position.getkategorie()); //  Kategorie

    values.put(KEY_BREITE, position.getBREITE()); // Breite

    values.put(KEY_BREITE, position.getLAENGE()); // Länge

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_POSITIONS, null, values);

    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}

// Getting single position
Position getPosition(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_POSITIONS, new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_KATEGORIE, KEY_LAENGE, KEY_BREITE  }, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Position position = new Position(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4));

    // return position
    return position;
}

// Getting All Positions
public List<Position> getAllPositions() {
    List<Position> positionList = new ArrayList<Position>();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_POSITIONS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Position position = new Position();
            position.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            position.setName(cursor.getString(1));
            position.setkategorie(cursor.getString(2));
            position.setLAENGE(cursor.getString(3));
            position.setBREITE(cursor.getString(4));

            // Adding position to list
            positionList.add(position);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // return position list
    return positionList;
}

// Updating single contact
public int updatePosition(Position position) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(KEY_NAME, position.getName());

    values.put(KEY_KATEGORIE, position.getkategorie());

    values.put(KEY_LAENGE, position.getLAENGE());

    values.put(KEY_BREITE, position.getBREITE());

    // updating row
    return db.update(TABLE_POSITIONS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(position.getID()) });

}

// Deleting single position
public void deletePosition(Position position) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    db.delete(TABLE_POSITIONS, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(position.getID()) });

    db.close();
}

// Getting positions Count
public int getContactsCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_POSITIONS;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}
}
```

**AndroidSQLiteTutorialActivity.java**

```
 package com.androidhive.androidsqlite;
public class AndroidSQLiteTutorialActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        /**
         * CRUD Operations
         * */
        // Inserting Positions
        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");
        db.addPosition(new Position("Hobbersdorfer Felder", "Landschaft" , "53.94966", "10.70343"));
        db.addPosition(new Position("Felder bei Pelzerhaken", "Landschaft", "54.10039", "10.83878"));
        db.addPosition(new Position("Felder bei Neustadt", "Landschaft" , "54.10713", "10.84201"));
        db.addPosition(new Position("Felder bei Gronenberg", "Landschaft" , "54.04454", "10.69646"));

        // Reading all positions
        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all positions..");
        List<Position> positions = db.getAllPositions();       

        for (Position cn : positions) {
            String log = "Id: "+cn.getID()+" ,Name: " + cn.getName() +" ,Kategorie: " + cn.getkategorie() + " ,Länge: " + cn.getLAENGE()+" ,Breite: " + cn.getBREITE();
                // Writing Contacts to log
        Log.d("Name: ", log);

        }
    }
}
```

**Position.java**

```
package com.androidhive.androidsqlite;

public class Position {

//private variables
int _id;
String kategorie;
String name;
String breite;
String laenge;

// Empty constructor
public Position(){

}
// constructor
public Position(int id, String kategorie, String name, String breite, String laenge){
    this._id = id;
    this.kategorie = kategorie;
    this.name = name;
    this.breite = breite;
    this.laenge = laenge;
}

// constructor
public Position(String kategorie, String name, String breite, String laenge){
    this.kategorie = kategorie;
    this.name = name;
    this.breite = breite;
    this.laenge = laenge;
}
// getting ID
public int getID(){
    return this._id;
}

// setting id
public void setID(int id){
    this._id = id;
}

// getting category
public String getkategorie(){
    return this.name;
}

// setting category
public void setkategorie(String kategorie){
    this.kategorie = kategorie;
    }

// getting name
public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}

// setting name
public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

// getting BREITE
public String getBREITE(){
    return this.breite;
}

// setting BREITE
public void setBREITE(String breite){
    this.breite = breite;

}

// getting LAENGE
public String getLAENGE(){
    return this.laenge;
}
// setting LAENGE
    public void setLAENGE(String laenge){
        this.laenge = laenge;

    }
}
```

Comment: replace `private static final String KEY_KATEGORIE = "kategorie";` by `private static final String KEY_KATEGORIE = "Kategorie";` The K should be upcase i think

Comment: Please @theboss222 format your code, it is painfull to read.

Comment: @Drakkin, i tried that, but still the same error

Comment: Can you show us the stacktrace please

Answer (score 0):

After researching your code i found next mistake.
I don't know will it help you in your question but you should correct next:

```
void addPosition(Position position) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // code
    values.put(KEY_BREITE, position.getBREITE()); // Breite

    values.put(KEY_BREITE, position.getLAENGE()); // Länge
    // code
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

You have copy-paste mistake here. Replace `KEY_BREITE` with `KEY_LAENGE`

Comment: i just set the Database version to "2", now it works finally without errors :) but thank you

Comment: ALWAYS, when you alter your database, you must increase the DATABASE_VERSION constant.

Comment: @theboss222 now i understand your mistake. You can set Database version to 1. Delete your app from mobile and install again.
If you changing your database structure, you should delete app and install it again. Because `onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)` is calling only once, while you oppening your app first time.